# ¿Cómo pasar datos desde Django a JS?

Tags: python, django

Sé cómo pasar datos desde Django a un template

```
return render(request, "index.html", {"args" : args})
```

Y luego en el template recogerlos así `{{args}}`
Esto mismo puedo hacerlo con js pero en el mismo template con la etiqueta `<script></script>`
Pero a la hora de hacerlo en un archivo de js, no encuentra estos parámetros

He probado con esto:

```
var data = JSON.parse("{{arg}}");
```

Y me devuelve este error en consola:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

¿Cómo puedo pasar datos desde mi vista de django a un documento aislado de JS?

Comment: Prueba con `<script>window.args= { args: {{ args|safe}}}</script>`

Comment: @EugeniBejan Mmmm, no, no funciona en mi index.js, es decir, me gustaría tener esos parámetros en un documento aislado de javascript, no es el html

Comment: No acabo de entender lo que quieres lograr. Si no entiendo mal tienes una serie de variables que pasas a la vista (esto es, una plantilla básicamente HTML) y quieres utilizar esas variables para ejecutar código que está en un fichero JS que enlazas desde esa misma vista, ¿es así o es otro tu planteamineto?

Comment: @Sokkian exactamente, es así, tengo X variables que las paso al template pero a la hora de utilizarlos en el fichero JS que tengo enlazado en este html, no puedo

Comment: @QuiqueFernandez, en tu `index.js` deberías de buscar los datos en `windows.args`. Por defecto django solo procesa el template en el lado del servidor y los otros archivos(css, js) no se procesan

Comment: @EugeniBejan Usando `window.args = { args: {{ args|safe}}}` me devuelve el siguiente error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'`

Comment: Lo estas haciendo en la parte del template?

Comment: @EugeniBejan Me da error en ambas

Comment: No uses el JSON.parse

Comment: @EugeniBejan Lo puedo hacer así, `<script>let data = "{{arg}}"</script>` y funciona, pero en el index.js no

Comment: @QuiqueFernandez, lo que te indica @Eugeni Bejan es correcto, debes por un lado asignar las variables a `window.args`, y por otra no debes hacer `JSON.parse`.

Comment: @EugeniBejan Vale! Acabo de hacerlo y funciona, poniendo `<script>window.args= { args: "{{args}}"}</script>` en el template y más tarde accediendo desde index.js, puedes responder a la propia pregunta y te lo daré como válido para ayudar a la comunidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como se menciono en los comentarios, para pasar los datos desde Django a javascript, primero debemos guardarlos en nuestro `window` mediante el uso de las plantillas, ya que django no procesa los archivos `.js` o `.css` y para eso hacemos lo siguiente en nuestro template

**TEMPLATE**

```
<script>
    window.data = { args: {{ args|safe}}}
</script>
```

Después si queremos trabajar con estos datos, simplemente tenemos que buscarlos en `window.data`, ejemplo

**ARCHIVO .JS**

```
....
let data = window.data
...
```

> Para saber que significa [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe) te recomiendo la documentación oficial

Comment: Agregar a que te refieres? Ya hay un link hacia la documentación